# How do I run xunit for asp.net 5 from command line for a single test

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit.net

How do I run xunit for asp.net 5 from command line for a single test

VS 2015 does something like this

`dnx.exe --appbase "\Mvc\test\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.IntegrationTests" Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost --port 9543 Microsoft.Framework.TestHost --port 11883 run --test Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.IntegrationTests.ActionParameterIntegrationTest.ActionParameter_NonSettableArrayModel_EmptyPrefix_DoesNotGetBound`

If I run this nothing happend

Answer (score 5):

Example for running a single test:
`dnx . test -method TestNamespace.TestClassName.TestMethodName`

Similarly for running all tests in a class
`dnx . test -class TestNamespace.TestClassName`

---

**UPDATE: Beta7 and after**

Example for running a single test:
`dnx test -method TestNamespace.TestClassName.TestMethodName`

Similarly for running all tests in a class
`dnx test -class TestNamespace.TestClassName`

Comment: I change my project.json and added %1 to the test command . `"commands": {"test": "xunit.runner.aspnet %1"}`.Now the test are working `dnx . test -class Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding.Test.ComplexModelDtoTest`